# create Observable<T> from result

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, rxjs

I am trying Angular2.

I noticed that the http service use `Observable` object instead of `Promise` (I don't like much that choice.. `async`/`await` are arriving).

In my service, I download a list of `Plants` from the webservice. Clicking on a plant I show the details using the routing.
But in this way when I go back, the plants are downloaded again (because the constructor is called again).

To avoid this I want to do something like:

```
public getPlants(): Observable<Plants[]>
{   
    if (this._plants != null)
        return Observable.fromResult (this._plants); //This method does not exists 

    return this._http.get('../../res/heroes.json')...
}
```

Is there a way to do that?
How can I import the `Observable` class in my ts file?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're just trying angular2, may I suggest you to give [aurelia](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.7/doc/article/getting-started) a try? ctrl-f for "httpclient" to see an example. It returns a Promise, like you want.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like `Observable.just`? (it is what it is called in other languages)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The method in TypeScript (or JavaScript for that matter) is called [`of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-of). [Learn rxjs has a nice tutorial as well](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of)

If you are using **rxjs6** you get everything from `rxjs`

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

public getPlants(): Observable<Plant[]> {
  const mocked: Plant[] = [
    { id: 1, image: 'hello.png' }
  ];
  // returns an Observable that emits one value, mocked; which in this case is an array,
  // and then a complete notification
  // You can easily just add more arguments to emit a list of values instead
  return of(mocked);
}
```

---

In previous version you imported the operator of from a different location

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

public getPlants(): Observable<Plant[]> {
  const mocked: Plant[] = [
    { id: 1, image: 'hello.png' }
  ];
  return of(mocked);
}
```

---

And before that you imported it as an extension for the Observable class

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

public getPlants(): Observable<Plants[]> {
    // this can be changed to a member variable of course
    let mocked: Plants[] = [{
        id: 1,
        image: "hello.png"
    }];
    return Observable.of(mocked);
}
```

Comment: I found that I needed to add `import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';` as well.

Comment: You can also `import from 'rxjs/Rx'` if you don't want to add all operators one by one.

Comment: I think this is older but i still wanted to keep this updated, Observable.create() is deprecated and suggesting to use new Observable(). and of() is also no longer in rxjs or deprecated. Or am i overlooking?

Answer (score 31):

This is my working solution:

```
if (this._heroes != null && this._heroes !== undefined) {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        observer.next(this._heroes);
        observer.complete();
    });
}
```

I hope that this is the best solution.

Comment: This is perfect.  This saved me a lot of time; thanks!

Comment: what's type of variable/parameter `observer` ?

Comment: It's a [Subscriber](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts). See [Observable.create()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create) and [new Observable()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-constructor-constructor) documentation.

Comment: `of`, below, is a better solution.

Comment: I think this is older but i still wanted to keep this updated, Observable.create() is deprecated and suggesting to use new Observable(). and of() is also no longer in rxjs or deprecated. Or am i overlooking?

Comment: Truly helped! Short and clean :)))