# Observable to dictionary in Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, dictionary, observable

Basically I'm trying to implement the equivalent of the C# LINQ [ToDictionary()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) method in Typescript.

As an example, if I have a list of Person (with properties say `int Id` and `string[] FirstNames`), I would like to have as an output, a dictionary with `Id` as the key, and the `FirstNames` as the value.

What I currently did in Typescript:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
    [index: string]: T;
}
```

Then I tried with map:

```
let result: IDictionary<string[]> = {}; 
let test = myObservable.map(b => b.map(item => result[item.moduleName] = item.jsFiles));
```

and with foreach

```
let test = myObservable.map(r => r.forEach(item => result[item.moduleName] = item.jsFiles));
```

Note that myObservable is of type `Observable<Abc[]>`

But it doesnt work...
The goal would be to have in the `test` variable an `Observable<IDictionary<string[]>>`

Comment: try `reduce` operator.

Comment: Already tried with that operator, do you have an exemple?

Comment: if you can share non successful attempt of reduce code you tried, that'll help more ppls to understand issue and easier to provide answers.

Comment: @OJKwon an example can be found in the kapantzak's post. unfortunately, it doesn't work with Observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of try and retry, I finally managed to have a working solution. I'm sharing it here, hopefully it will helps someone else in the future:

```
let result = myObservable.map(data => {
             return data.reduce((acc: IDictionary<string[]>, val: T): IDictionary<string[]> => {
                acc[val.moduleName] = val.jsFiles;
                return acc;
             }, initialValue);
        });
```

Thanks to @kapantzak which took me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach using reduce ([DEMO](https://jsbin.com/yazazo/edit?html,js,console)):

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
    [index:string]: T
}

interface IObservable {
    Id: number,
    FirstNames: string[]
}


let myObservable: IObservable[] = [
    {
        Id: 0,
        FirstNames: ['John', 'Mary', 'Tom']
    },
    {
        Id: 1,
        FirstNames: ['Jack', 'Zak']
    }
];

let result: IDictionary<string[]> = myObservable.reduce((acc: IDictionary<string[]>, val: IObservable): IDictionary<string[]> => {
    acc[val.Id] = val.FirstNames;
    return acc;        
}, {});

console.log(result); // { 0: ["John","Mary","Tom"], 1: ["Jack","Zak"] }
```

**EDIT**

Try this (untested) according to [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660010/create-observablet-from-result)

```
let observableResult: Observable<IDictionary<string[]>> = Observable.of(result);
```

Comment: I have the following error with this code: `TS2345: Argument of type '(acc: IDictionary<string[]>, val: T) => IDictionary<string[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(acc: {}, value: T[], index: number) => {}'.
      Types of parameters 'val' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.`

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I have an Observable array and not just an array as in your example... so basically, in your example, it would be a Observable<IObservable[]>. Not sure if this solution is working in this case?

Comment: Not sure to understand your edit (sorry, I'm new to Typescript)?! My variable `myObservable` is of type `Observable<IObservable[]>`, so not sure when do I have to put then `Observable.of` ?